# Is there any tool which allows to set any arbitrary window title in the taskbar minimized window?

Tags: windows-xp, taskbar

I work on a lot of folders and applications simultaneously. By default, the folder windows when minimized show the first few characters of the folder name. In my case, many subfolders have same name (under different parent folders), and I will rather like to see the parent folder name as the title when minimized. Is there a way I can specify any arbitrary title?

Alternately, if this is not possible, is there a tool using which I can group any set of application windows into 1 logical group and give a name to that group, which should show as a single minimized window in taskbar. By default, taskbar groups windows of same application. But what I want is a feature where I can decide which application windows form 1 logical group.

I am using Windows XP SP2, 32 bit.

Comment: In the folder view properties there's a setting "show full path in title" (or something similar, I've the system in Italian locale)... check it, apply settings to all folders, and you're done. (I do that on every system I install)

Comment: But that wont work in my case. Because the parent folder title which I want to display is also buried inside many folders, and displaying the full path in the title bar will only be able to show first few characters or as many as can fit. So that won't help. I will need to take the mouse pointer to the minimized window to make out which folder it represents, which again is cumbersome when you are working with 8-10 folders at a time.

Comment: Well, I was able to find an answer to my requirements. wsTaskborg Taskbar Organizer can do both the things which I require, and it works on Windows XP.

http://download.cnet.com/wsTaskborg/3000-2072_4-10632012.html

http://w-shadow.com/wstaskborg/

Hope many others will find it useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I was able to find an answer to my requirements. wsTaskborg Taskbar Organizer can do both the things which I require, and it works on Windows XP.

http://download.cnet.com/wsTaskborg/3000-2072_4-10632012.html

http://w-shadow.com/wstaskborg/

Hope many others will find it useful!

Comment: Time is running out for XP, solutions for W7 would be more useful in the long run, nice find by the way. +1